# Transfer-Encoding: chunked sent twice (chunk size included in response body)

Tags: php, apache, http

I'm using Apache 2.2 and PHP 7.0.1. I force chunked encoding with `flush()` like in this example:

```
<?php

header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
echo "hello";
flush();
echo "world";

die;
```

And I get unwanted characters at the beginning and end of the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK                       
Date: Fri, 09 Sep 2016 15:58:20 GMT   
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)        
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.9               
Connection: close                     
Transfer-Encoding: chunked            
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

a                                     
helloworld                            
0
```

The first one is the chunk size in hex (10 = A). I'm using [Klein](https://github.com/klein/klein.php) as PHP router and I have found that **the problem comes up only when the HTTP status header is rewritten**. I guess there is a problem with my Apache config, but I wasn't able to figure it out.

**Edited:** My problem had nothing to do with Apache but Nginx and  `chunked_transfer_encoding` directive. Check the answer below.

Comment: What exactly are the unwanted characters you're seeing?

Comment: @JasonHoetger The "a" (10 in hex, as there are 10 characters) and the trailing "0". They are included in body, so it breaks my HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Joe pointed out before, that is the normal behavior when **Chunked transfer enconding** is enabled. My tests where not accurate because I was requesting **Apache** directly on the server. Actually, when I was experiencing the problem in Chrome I was querying a **Nginx** service as a proxy for Apache.

By running `tcpdump` I realized that Nginx was **rechunking responses**, but only when rewritting HTTP status header (`header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK')`) in PHP. The solution to sending `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` twice is to set `chunked_transfer_encoding off` in the `location` context of my Nginx **.php handler**.

Answer (score 3):

This is how [`Transfer-Encoding: chunked` works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). The extra characters you're seeing are part of the encoding, rather than the body.

A client that understands the encoding will not include them in the result; a client that doesn't doesn't support HTTP/1.1, and should be considered bugged.